# How get only first td element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose to have this html code:

```
<tr id="row_1">
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Text</tr>
</tr>

<tr id="row_2">
 <td>2</td>
 <td>home</tr>
</tr>

<tr id="row_n">
 <td>n</td>
 <td>n row</tr>
</tr>
```

I need to take only the first td element in a row, so I do:

```
$('[id^="row_"] > td ').each(function(){

});
```

But this jquery code it doesn't work because it gets me all first td children of tr but I want only the first td child of tr. Anyone can help?

Comment: How about `.eq(0)`?

Comment: Yes, get each tr, then push the first td of each tr into an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with this:

```
$('[id^="row_"] > td:first-child')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use :first-child

You can do this using .each().

Example:

```
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:first-child` like this:

`var firstTd = $('td:first-child');`

ref: https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/